# Excel Add In connection to Azure SignalR not working

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to connect my Excel Add In to Azure SignalR. I already connected a WPF app - but apparently ASP.NET Core does not support Office Add-Ins (getting a DisposeAsync not implemented exception) so I am using the assembly Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client instead.

My code so far:

```
var query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
query.Add("version", "1.0");
query.Add("Authorization", GenerateAccessToken());
query.Add("hub", _hubName);

connection = new HubConnection(_endpoint, query);
connection.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + GenerateAccessToken());
hubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy(_hubName);

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

connection.Start().Wait();
```

Executing "connection.Start().Wait()" gives my the following error:

```
HttpClientException: StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: 
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
  Date: Sun, 25 Jun 2023 18:47:53 GMT
  Content-Length: 146
  Content-Type: text/html
}
```

The _endpoint is "https://(me).service.signalr.net" replacing (me) with the correct name.

The odd thing is when looking in fiddler i get code 200 with the following call from the WPF app:

```
POST https://<me>.service.signalr.net/client/negotiate?hub=default&negotiateVersion=1
```

When i run the code above it gives me:

```
GET https://<me>.service.signalr.net/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=%5B%7B%22Name%22:%22default%22%7D%5D&version=1.0&Authorization=(access_token.....)
```

I don't know how to change the endpoint (from signalr to client) or the method. I cannot put parameters on the endpoint without it throwing an exception.

If I fill out the query list I seems like a wrong endpoint.

Comment: Hope this help [Git](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-troubleshoot-guide.md)

Comment: Office web add-ins act like a regular static web application. As soon as you implement that feature in the web application you can do that for Office add-ins.